# Chart.js - access yAxes properties

Tags: arrays, charts, chart.js

From everything I've seen we access the y axis on a 2-axis cartesian graph like so:
`chart.options.scales.yAxes[0]`
However I get 'undefined'.  This despite the fact that my chart is generated with the following dictionary:

```
{
      type: 'line',
      data: {
        ...
      },
      options: {
        scales: {
          yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
              beginAtZero: false
            }
          }]
        },
        tooltips: {
          enabled: false,
        }
      }
}
```

This suggests the same method of access as I attempted.  However `chart.options.scales.yAxes` returns object Object, so that is defined.  Why can I not access it as an Array, which other examples I've seen, and the method of defining the chart, clearly show it to be?

Comment: what version of Chart.js are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 3.1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `options` are defined in the Chart.js version 2 syntax.

`scales.[x/y]` axes arrays were removed in Chart.js version 3 (see `specific changes`). Scales are now configured directly to `options.scales` object with the object key being the scale id.

```
options: {
  scales: {
    y: {
      beginAtZero: false
    }     
  }    
}
```

It seems that your `chart.options.scales` are overwritten with default values by Chart.js because they don't comply with the expected format. This would explain why `chart.options.scales.yAxes` returns an `Object` instead of an `Array`.

Comment: Thank you for the help.  The Chart.js documentation I was able to find still showed the 2.x format.